# 5920#0: *52 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream,

Tags: javascript, gwt, nginx, ejabberd, emit

I tried to run emit(a gwt implemention of xmpp client) with ejabberd,and it works fine.
   I noticed that the developers of emit use a java servlet to proxy request to ejabberd:

```
https://github.com/EmiteGWT/hablar/blob/master/src/main/java/de/spieleck/servlets/ProxyServlet.java),
```

And I want to bypass this proxy,so I follow this post:

```
http://anders.conbere.org/blog/2011/05/03/get_xmpp_-_bosh_working_with_ejabberd_firefox_and_strophe/
```

But javascript client(complied from emit) takes long time to connect to ejabbered,and then disconnect quickly,and the nginx error log like this:

```
2012/10/06 17:04:33 [error] 5920#0: *52 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /http-bind HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "http://111.186.4.11:5280/http-bind", host: "127.0.0.1", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1/hablartest/HablarTest1.html"
```

Can anybody tell me what I did wrong?

My configuration:
   firefox-13  ejabberd-2.1.11  nginx-1.0.5  ubuntu-11.10

(since same client code(js code complied from gwt) with servlent proxy works fine,so I think it may be a nginx configuration problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally,I found out the problem:my proxy configuration like this:

```
 location ~ ^/http-bind {       
         proxy_pass http://localhost:5280;
 }
```

So nginx will redirect all requests from 127.0.0.1:80 to localhost:5280

This will work fine if I disconnected from Internet,but if I connect to Internet,my hosts file becomes:

```
127.0.0.1       luya    localhost.localdomain   localhost
111.186.4.11    luya    localhost.localdomain   localhost
```

From my understanding,localhost will be "taken" as either 127.0.0.1 or 111.186.4.11 randomly,so it is this confusing caused problem.Solution is simple,changing proxy configuration

from

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:5280;
```

to

```
 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5280;
```